# Инструменты разработка GUI на Qt/QML под Desktop для больших мониторов / Эмуляторы мониторов Linux

Tags: linux, qt, gui, qml, desktop

Я занимаюсь разработкой GUI на Qt/QML для Linux. Мне необходимо делать GUI для монитора с разрешением больше, чем мой собственный. Есть ли какие-нибудь инструменты или эмуляторы мониторов для этого?

Comment: Больше имеет значение соотношение сторон, а не количество пикселей. А в целом, используйте менеджер размещения компонентов и не парьтесь зря

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596887/how-to-scale-the-resolution-display-of-the-desktop-and-or-applications